# Using 'db','dw' in MVC++ assembler adds

Tags: model-view-controller, assembly, nasm, masm

What should I use instead of

```
__asm
{
    db 0EAh
    dw 0000h
    dw 0FFFFh
}
```

( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx )
in MVC++?

Comment: I'm trying to reboot system using assembler block, however mvc++ doesn't accept data directives and operators.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx

Comment: you can define 3 variables as uint8_t, uint16_t, uint16_t and assign them those values. But I'm not 100% sure I follow.

Comment: as c++ or asm code? because it doesn't recognize it as c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _asm {
      mov ax, 40h 
      mov ds, ax 
      mov word ptr ds:[72h], 1234h
      jmp dword ptr cs:0ffff0000h
    }
```

Thanks to @gusbro's comment I finally understand what you are trying to do. I'm not sure if this will work since I don't have a windows machine to test this, but you should give it a try.

> warm is a  far call to FFFF:0000h with 40:72h set to 1234h
>
> cold is a far call to FFFF:0000h with 40:72h set to 0

Comment: I don't think any of these pieces of code will work in (user-mode) Windows processes. You can make your PC reboot quite easily if you write a kernel mode driver...

Comment: @gusbro I can't remember the last time I used windows, I just tried to help with the information I had available. On the bright side there's always system ("shutdown /r"); i guess

Comment: Hehe, yes. My point was that you won't have privileges to do a reset programmatically. shutdown /r will work only if you have the necessary rights to do a reboot

Answer (score 0):

You can emit opcodes with this [intrinsic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253948%28VS.80%29.aspx) :
__emit(int opcode)

You might be able to execute your code by secuentially emmiting the opcodes. 
However, I don't think you will succeed in rebooting your machine this way...

Comment: even if I'll use this in booting progress?

Comment: You seem to be trying to do the "jump_to_bios" restart. Look at the linux source about how they do it (not as simple as just doing the jump). Look in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c